# Rails 3.1 Jquery helper methods (//= require jquery_ujs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this file in the assets pipeline

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

contains some helper methods for jquery in Rails 3.1

I know that

```
"remote => 'true'
```

triggers jquery to make an ajax request

and

```
:update => "blah"
```

would tell  jquery to insert content into the id "blah"

and

```
:position => "after"
```

would tell jquery to place it after any other content in the id

Are there any other helper methods defined in this file? Where can I find out?  I looked at the rails api  http://api.rubyonrails.org/  but didn't see anything

Do you know any other helper methods? or do you know where to find out what they are?